# Create an Installer package for Installation on WAMP

Tags: php, installation, wamp

I have developed a PHP web application, now I am thinking about deploying it on Windows.

To ease my deployment, I plan to create an installer for it. This installer should do the following:

1. Check for Pre-requisites such as Apache, MySQL etc, install them if they are not available
2. Put the PHP application on Application folder, and in this process set the port number, create a conf file for the application, update the httpd.conf to make sure that it refers to the application-specific conf file.
3. Run database setup script and database population script that I prepared.
4. Set the database setting in the application config files so that they are pointing at the correct database.

I am looking for a installer to help me on this regard, something like [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com). Of course, I still have to write a lot of custom actions code for it, which is something I really hate.My question now is that is there anyone who has done all these stuffs and are willing to share his code, so that I don't have to do everything from scratch?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for this http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/. Bitrock is used by a few big projects like SugarCRM, etc to get their LAMP stack on other computers. Give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

You could try movAmp. This will pack your application to one working executable, including apache/php/mysql.
Your application therefore should be aware if it is installed or not, say redirect to an install-script on first hit.

> Movamp is an environment of
>   development to be taken.
>
> MovAMP was conceived to hold on a key
>   USB or any other support of weak
>   capacity. Connect it up in a computer
>   equipped with Microsoft Windows and
>   you have access to a server web,a
>   database and INTERPRETER PHP. If
>   MovAMP succeeds in contenting himself
>   of not much of space, he can offer
>   also installed on a workstation.
>
> Comparable in EasyPhp or WAMP5, MovAMP
>   inserts APACHE 2.0.54, MYSQL 4.1.12,
>   PHP 5.0.4 and phpMyAdmin 2.6.2-pl1.
>   Exits of the development of free
>   software, these technologies proved
>   their fastness and their stability.
>
> Once thrown, he adds an icon to the
>   zone of notification allowing to stop
>   the server Apache and MySQL or to
>   achieve the reception of the site or
>   in phpMyAdmin.

[Link](http://en.kioskea.net/telecharger/telecharger-191-movamp)